# sed, awk or perl: Pattern range match, print 45 lines then add record delimiter

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have a file containing records delimited by the pattern /#matchee/. These records are of varying lengths ...say 45 - 75 lines. They need to *ALL* be 45 lines and still maintain the record delimiter. Records can be from different departments, department name is on line 2 following a blank line. So record delimiter could be thought of as simply /^#matchee/ or /^matchee/ followed by \n. There is a *Deluxe* edition of this problem and a *Walmart* edition ...

**DELUXE EDITION**

Pull each record by pattern range so I can sort records by department. Eg., with sed

```
sed -n '/^DEPARTMENT NAME/,/^#matchee/{p;}' mess-o-records.txt
```

Then, Print *only the first 45 lines* of each record in the file to conform to
    the 45 line constraint.

Finally, make sure the result still has the record delimiter on line 45.

**WALMART EDITION**

Same as above, but instead of using a range, just use the record delimiter.

**STATUS**

My attempt at this might clarify what I'm trying to do.

```
sed -n -e '/^DEPARTMENT-A/,/^#matchee/{p;}' -e '45q' -e '$s/.*/#matchee/' mess-o-records.txt
```

This doesn't work, of course, because sed is operating on the entire file at each command.
I need it to operate on each range match *not the whole file*.

**SAMPLE INPUT - 80 Lines** ( truncated for space )

```
<blank line>
DEPARTMENT-A
Office space 206
Anonymous, MI 99999

Harold O Nonymous
Buckminster Abbey
Anonymous, MI 99999

item A     Socket B     45454545
item B     Gizmo Z      76767676
<too many lines here>
<way too many lines here>  


#matchee
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT - now only 45 lines**

```
<blank line>
DEPARTMENT-A
Office space 206
Anonymous, MI 99999

Harold O Nonymous
Buckminster Abbey
Anonymous, MI 99999

item A     Socket B     45454545
item B     Gizmo Z      76767676
<Record now equals exactly 45 lines>  
<yet record delimiter is maintained>

#matchee
```

**CLARIFICATION UPDATE**

I will never need more than the first 40 lines if this makes things easier. Maybe the process would be:

- Match pattern(s)
- Print first 40 lines.
- Pad to appropriate length. Eg., 45 lines.
- Tack delimiter back on. Eg., #matchee

I think this would be more flexible -- Ie., can handle record shorter than 45 lines.

Here's a riff based on @Borodin's Perl example below:

```
my $count = 0;
$/ = "#matchee";    

while (<>) {
    if (/^REDUNDANCY.*DEPT/) {
        print;
        $count = 0;
    }   
    else {
        print if $count++ < 40; 
        print "\r\n" x 5; 
        print "#matchee\r\n";
    }   
}
```

This add 5 newlines to each record + the delimiting pattern /#matchee/. So it's wrong -- but it illustrates what I want.

Print 40 lines based on department -- pad -- tack delimiter back on.

Comment: It would probably help if you gave examples of your input and expected output.

Comment: Have you tried piping each of your sed `-e` commands into each other?

Comment: @Bubnoff: I hope you mean 45, not 65? Else you've completely lost me!

Comment: Sorry @Borodin, meant 45 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. Not sure about the bit about *pull each record by pattern range*. Is `#matchee` always followed by a blank line and then the department line? So in fact record number 2?

This Perl fragment does what I understand you need.

If you prefer you can put the input file on the command line and drop the `open` call. Then the loop would have to be `while (<>) { ... }`.

Let us know if this is right so far, and what more you need from it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'mess-o-records.txt' or die $!;

my $count = 0;

while (<$fh>) {
  if (/^#matchee/) {
    print;
    $count = 0;
  }
  else {
    print if $count++ < 45;
  }
}
```

Comment: So far, this seems to work perfectly. Need to test more. How would you handle records that were less than 45 lines?

Comment: As to your pattern range question: I'd like to be able to define a record as starting with a pattern based on department and ending with the delimiting pattern.

Comment: How would you solve this if $/ was set to #matchee, then matched on the department name ...Eg., /^REDUNDANCY.*DEPT$/?

Comment: Records shorter than 45 lines are simply copied in their entirety. If you read the entire record in at one time you then have to split it into lines to limit it to 45. I suggest you trim the records to length as a first step and then sort them afterwards in a second pass.

Comment: How would you go about trimming each record. I am trying using the $. operator and getting nowhere.

Comment: Why can't you use the code I have written? I thought it was working OK for you? `$.` will count the number of records, so if you are changing the value of `$/` an entire record counts as one. You must either read the data by lines as I did or read records and split it into lines once you've read it, which seems pointless.

Comment: I'd like to pull only the first 40 lines ...then pad them out to the number of lines I need in order to handle unknown record lengths. Won't the code above fail on records less then 45 lines?

Comment: The code copies each record up to 45 lines and then discards the rest. Short records will be copied in their entirety. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already had an accepted answer, but I figured I'd post an awk example for anyone interested.  It's not 100%, but it gets the job done.

*Note* This numbers the lines so you can verify the script is working as expected.  Remove the `i,` from `print i, current[i]` to remove the line numbers.

**dep.awk**

```
BEGIN { RS = "#matchee\n\n" }

$0 ~ /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/ {
    split($0, current, "\n")
    for (i = 1; i <= 45; i++) {
        print i, current[i];
    }
    print "#matchee\n"
}
```

In this example, you begin the script by setting the record separator (**RS**) to *"#matchee\n\n"*.  There are two newlines because the first ends the line on which #matchee occurs and the second is the blank line on its own.

The match validates that a record contains letters or numbers to be valid.  You could also check that the match starts with 'DEPARTMENT-', but this would fail if there is a stray newline.  Checking the content is the safest route. Because this uses a block record (i.e., DEPARTMENT-A through #matchee), you could either pass **$0** through awk or sed again, or use the awk split function and loop through 45 lines.  In awk, the arrays aren't zero-indexed.

The print function includes a newline, so the block ends with `print "#matchee\n"` only instead of the double `\n` in the record separator variable.

You could also drop the same awk script into a bash script and change the number of lines and field separator.  Of course, you should add validations and whatnot, but here's the start:

**dep.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# prints the first n lines within every block of text delimited by splitter
splitter=$1
numlines=$2

awk 'BEGIN { RS="'$1'\n\n" }
$0 ~ /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/ {
    split($0, current, "\n")
    for(i=1;i<='$numlines';i++) {
        print i, current[i]
    }
    print "'$splitter'", "\n"
}' $3
```

Make the script executable and run it.

```
./dep.sh '#matchee' 45 input.txt > output.txt
```

I added these files to a gist so you could also verify the [output](https://gist.github.com/2201331#file_output.txt)

Comment: Thanks for the awk. Easily plugged into my current script.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
D="DEPARTMENT-A" M="#matchee"
sed '/'"$D/,/$M"'/{/'"$D"'/{h;d};H;/'"$M"'/{x;:a;s/\n/&'"$M"'/45;tb;s/'"$M"'/\n&/;ta;:b;s/\('"$M"'\).*/\1/;p};d}' file
```

Explanation:

- Focus on range of lines `/DEPARTMENT/,/#matchee/`

  - At start of range move pattern space (PS) to hold space (HS) and delete PS `/DEPARTMENT/{h;d}`
  - All subsequent lines in the range append to HS and delete `H....;d`
  - At end of range:`/#matchee/`

    - Swap to HS `x`
    - Test for 45 lines in range and if successful append `#matchee` at the 45th line `s/\n/&#matchee/45`
    - If previous substitution was successful branch to label `b`. `tb`
    - If previous substitution was unsuccessful insert a linefeed before `#matchee` `s/'"$M"'/\n&/` thus lengthening a short record to 45 lines.
    - Branch to label `a` and test for 45 lines etc . `ta`
    - Replace the first occurrence of `#matchee` to the end of the line by it's self. `s/\('"$M"'\).*/\1/` thus shortening a long record to 45 lines.
    - Print the range of records. `p`
- All non-range records pass through untouched.

Answer (score 0):

TXR Solution ( http://www.nongnu.org/txr )

For illustration purposes using the fake data, I shorten the requirement from 40 lines to 12 lines. We find records beginning with a department name, delimited by `#matchee`. We dump them, chopped to no more than 12 lines, with `#matchee` added again.

```
@(collect)
@  (all)
@dept
@  (and)
@    (collect)
@line
@    (until)
#matchee
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(end)
@(output)
@  (repeat)
@{line[0..12] "\n"}
#matchee
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Here, the `dept` variable is expected to come from a `-D` command line option, but of course the code can be changed to accept it as an argument and put out a usage if it is missing.

Run on the sample data:

```
$ txr -Ddept=DEPARTMENT-A trim-extract.txr mess-o-records.txt 
DEPARTMENT-A
Office space 206
Anonymous, MI 99999

Harold O Nonymous
Buckminster Abbey
Anonymous, MI 99999

item A     Socket B     45454545
item B     Gizmo Z      76767676

<too many lines here>
#matchee
```

The blank lines before `DEPARTMENT-A` are gone, and there are exactly 12 lines, which happen to include one line of the `<too many ...>` junk.

Note that the semantics of `@(until)` is such that the `#matchee` is excluded from the collected material. So it is correct to unconditionally add it in the `@(output)` clause.  This program will work even if a record happens to be shorter than 12 lines before `#matchee` is found.

It will not match a record if `#matchee` is not found.